# DHTMLX Scheduler - Events show but then disappear when loading data from multiple sources

Tags: javascript, json, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

When loading event data from multiple json sources, events will display but then will quickly disappear at random. This only occurs when loading many events (400+) from 3 or more data sources. Sometimes they will all display correctly, but most of the time the majority of them disappear.

Note: Many of the events being loaded are more than a year long.

Example using the multiple source extension:

```
scheduler.load(["data1.json", "data2.json", "data3.json"], "json");
```

I am suspicious that the events are being filtered after initialisation but can't find out why. This happens on all views.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Aliaksandr for providing the solution on DHTMLX forums:

> probably this is happening because of collision of ids between the
>   items from different data sources. When scheduler loads an item which
>   has the same id as one of already existing items - it assumes it is
>   the same data item, the old one is getting replaced.
>
> You can try adding a prefix to ids depending on data source, in order
>   to prevent collisions

Forum Link: http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=38299&p=119369#p119369